# Packing two values into one int

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I'm reverse engineering a protocol and need some help with some of the data transmission.

In the data, a value `x` is stored as a single byte. This piece of data, `x`, is then turned into values `a` and `b` using the code below. `a` has a maximum value of 10 and `b` has a maximum value of 3.

Here is the code used in the software to extrapolate `a` and `b` from `x`. My question is: how can I generate a value for `x`, given `a` and `b`?

```
int x = data.get_byte();
int a = x >> 2;
int b = x & 3;
```

Comment: The will not allow for a value of `b` bigger than 3.

Comment: @ScottHunter it only represents a n/s/e/w value so that's fine

Comment: So "`a` and `b` both have a maximum value of around 10" is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost literally the reverse of your *extrapolation*:

`(a << 2) | b`

Answer (score 2):

b is represented in the last two bits of x. The & 3 basically clears all bits except the last 2 (because 3 is represented by 000....00011)

a is represented by all except the last two bits of x. The >> 2 shifts all the bits two places to the right, removing whatever bits were previously stored in the last 2 places.

Given a and b, you can construct x by basically doing the reverse of your the two operations which is `(a << 2) | b`